# How to create an unique combination of array elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object where I want to create every unique combination of objects as its own array. The combinations also need to include a different number of elements and should work regardless of the elements provided. To simplify the problem let's say we have the following array.

`let arr = [1, 2, 3];`

The result in this situation would be the following:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I have looked for a solution and have found an approach using cartesian products, but this doesn't really seem to apply for this case since i need unique combinations and no replicates. How can I a approach this problem with Javascript?

Comment: Combinations and permutations are pretty well covered by searching the web (and SO), and can be done manually or via libraries. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page; at the least you should post what has been attempted so far, and how (specifically) it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not my homework. I am approaching a problem I have not faced before and can't seem to find an optimal solution. Of course I am not very experienced with alghorithms so I kindly ask you to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @gogibogi4 "Optimal" isn't actionable; optimized for what? What *specific* issue are you having? This is a very well researched topic and there are *lots* of implementations, with varying tradeoffs, documented all over the place.

Comment: I would like to aviod using to many iterations since this will result in bad performance. Could you provide me with a link where I can research more on the problem? Surely there must also be an alghorithm that I can use in similiar situations.

Comment: @gogibogi4 This is something I believe you should be able to research on your own--that's why I'm asking for specifics, because there must be *some* reason your own research has fallen short. That's also why I'm asking for what you've already tried, and why it doesn't meet whatever goals you have.

Comment: Google "site:stackoverflow.com javascript generate combinations array" brings back *plenty* of useful results.  This is a common homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and return an array of items.

```js
function combinations(array) {
    function iter(index, temp = []) {
      if (!index--) return;
        iter(index, temp);
        result.push(temp = [array[index], ...temp]);
        iter(index, temp);
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(array.length);
    return result;
}

combinations([1, 2, 3]).forEach(a => console.log(a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be defined recursively in pseudo-Javascript:

```
function combos(arr) {
  if arr is empty
    return arr;
  else {
    result = [];
    // for every combination from the rest of the list
    for x in combos( arr.slice(1) ) {
       // get that combination w/o arr[0]
       result.push( x );  
       x.push( arr[0] );  
       // … and the combination w/ arr[0]   
       result.push( x );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a solution on my own. I created two helper functions for making the problem easier. The first one is just a function for switching array indexes and the second one is a recursive function that let's me remove an element at each recursive call and sums the result to its own array.

By iterating for every element i can get all the n-length combinations for the array. Then I remove the first element and repeat the procedure until i am out of elements. This will give me all the solutions, but they will have duplicates.

By sorting them ascending and converting them to a string i can create a Set out of them, which will create unique strings. The last step is to remove the duplicates and I end up with all the combinations.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

let result = [];

while (arr.length !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result = [...result, ...levelCombo(arr)];

        arr = switchIndex(arr, 0, i);
    }

    arr = arr.slice(1);
}

result = result.map(el => JSON.stringify(el.sort()));

let uniqueResult = [...new Set(result)].map(el => JSON.parse(el));

console.log(uniqueResult);

function switchIndex(arr, a, b) {
    let val1 = arr[a];
    let val2 = arr[b];

    arr[a] = val2;
    arr[b] = val1;

    return arr;
}

function levelCombo(arr) {
    let result = [];

    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result.push(arr[i]);
    }

    result = [result, ...levelCombo(arr.slice(1))];

    return result;
}
```

For the input [1, 2, 3] the printed result will be the following:

```
    [ 
        [ 1, 2, 3 ], 
        [ 2, 3 ], 
        [ 3 ], 
        [ 1, 3 ], 
        [ 1, 2 ], 
        [ 2 ], 
        [ 1 ] 
    ]
```